# On widget ready in CKEditor

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

How do i trigger something when a widget is ready in CKEditor? I see that widgets have a [ready event](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.plugins.widget), and i need to execute some code after everything is ready.

I tried something like this:

```
 editor.widgets.add("cool widget name", {
            button: "Do stuff",
            template: "<span class='class'><span class='some-class'></span><span class='some-otherclass'></span></span>",
            editables: {
                content: {
                    selector: ".class",
                    allowedContent: 'span[*](*);'
                }
            },
            allowedContent: 'span[*];',
            upcast: function (element) {
                return element.name == 'span' && element.hasClass(".class");
            },
            init: function () {
                $(this).on('ready', function() {
                    // stuff
                }
                doStuff(this);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

... So i just removed the jQuery stuff and it seems to work.

```
init: function () {
           this.on('ready', function() {
                // stuff
            }
            doStuff(this);
        }
```